# C# Inheriting from a SortedList

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I would like to ask how can I correctly inherit a class from a sorted list:

```
public class Plates : SortedList<string,Plate> {
}
```

The code above does not give me errors and I am confused, because for inheriting Enumerable I needed to add additional methods to enumerate elements.

Can someone show me how I could correctly add indexing of the sorted list and add methods?

Should I write smth similar to code below to store Plate objects in this class. I really do not have much experience inheriting other class than IEnumerable.

```
public class Plates : SortedList<string,Plate> {
    SortedList<string,Plate> plateList = new  SortedList<string,Plate>();
}
```

Comment: I think the bigger question is: Why do you want to "inherit a class from a sorted list"?

Comment: IEnumerable is an interface, SortedList is a class. That's why you don't need additional methods in the second case.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface. It's not inherited but implemented. It comes with no default implementation of its own, despite having many extension methods operating on `IEnumerable` "for free".

Comment: So what is your problem with `to add additional methods to enumerate elements` ? - You can just enumerate `this` eg: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tz4LFI

Comment: `because for inheriting Enumerable` Can you point us to this `Enumerable` class so we can see what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override and handle the actions on a Sorted list, I would suggest to go with composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class Plates: : IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Plate>> {
    private SortedList<string,Plate> st;
}
```

This will force you to implement the `IEnumerable` methods and difirentiate the implementation using the `SortedList` functionality you want.

As mentioned, classes (if they are not `abstract`) will not force you to implement anything if you inherit them.

Comment: Don't you mean `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Plate>>` or perhaps just `IEnumerable<Plate>`?

Comment: Would it be possible to look at my code above? I am concerned if it is right and whether the elements would be sorted?

Comment: Yes on both. It will be sorted. I don't think you even need to implement the `IEnumerable`, just use the `SortedList` directly.